# SSH подключается только по локальной сети. А нужно сделать чтобы можно было подключится из любой

Tags: apache, сервер, centos, ssh, iptables

использую Centos 6 + Apache + Nginx

Пытаюсь подключится к серверу по ssh использую программу PuTTy но у меня не получается установить соединение из другой сети. 
Сервер почему то разрешает к нему подключится только из локальной сети.

Вот мой iptables

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Jul 23 14:57:37 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [7:460]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:612]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP 
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jul 23 14:57:37 2019
```

Сейчас заметил одну старнность значит проверил я через сервис [проверки открытых портов](https://portscaner.ru/)
И там пишет что порт 22 закрыт хотя в iptables четко написано правило его открытия. 
Непонятно как-то и  скорее всего проблема заключается в этом. 
Есть ли у вас какие нибудь мысли по этому поводу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[root@94 ~]# iptables -S

-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. очистите все правила netfilter-а. 2. что значит «не даёт»?

Comment: Ну не получается подключится по ssh из другой сети. вот что это значит_)

Comment: Ну я обычно подключаюсь к SSH по PuTTy. Когда я нахожусь дома то соединение происходит успешно, а когда пытаюсь подключится из другой сети то уже подключится не получается.

Comment: понимаете, вы привели ничтожно мало информации. постарайтесь облегчить жизнь тем, кто хочет ответить на вопрос, но затрудняется изложить в одном ответе все те тысячи сочетаний и вариаций, которые **могут** быть описаны тем мизором сведений, которые вы перечислили в вопросе.

Comment: Добавил немного информации. Взгляните может что нибудь посоветуете?

Comment: @EMOMALIEV, а может причина не в вашем сервере, а в ближайшем к нему маршрутизаторе - он рубит доступ к  22 порту ?

Comment: давайте я приведу одну из множества вариаций описанного вами, но изложенную так, что ответ разумного размера вполне можно дать: «сервер подключен к маршрутизатору, подключенному к провайдеру. все внешние обращения к выделенному ip-адресу марш-р пробрасывает на сервер. с машины, подключ. к этому же марш-ру, можно подключиться к серверу на порт 22, а из внешного мира — нет. хотя, наприме, http-трафик из внешнего мира к серверу проходит нормально.». ответ тут будет однозначный: обратитесь к провайдеру.

Comment: Ну в роутере у меня настроен DMZ и вроде я не прописывал запрет на порт 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для начала проверим `iptables`:

   ```
   iptables -F
   iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
   iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
   iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
   ```
2. Если заработало:

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -P INPUT DROP
   ```

   Если продолжило работать, читаем маны по `iptables`, пробуем продолжать настраивать. Если работать перестало, возможно я где-то ошибся.
3. Если не заработало:
4. Можно изменить порт `ssh` на `20022` и проверить фильтры аплинка.

   В файле: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` Заменить строку: `# Port 22` на `Port 20022`
   Перезапустить `sshd`: `service sshd restart`

   Описываем схему подключение к интернет. Обращаем внимание на `NAT`. Смотрим на входящий трафик: `tcpdump`. Тут может быть много вариантов.

Comment: Понял вас. Значит сейчас попробовал и получилась такая картина:
1 вариант-работает только порт 80. 
2 вариант-ничего не работает

Comment: Пробуй пункт 4, совместно с пунктом 1.

Comment: Спасибо изменение стандартного порта ssh на другой решило проблему. Но хотелось бы узнать есть ли у вас какие то мысли по этому поводу(Почему он так себя ведет?). Так как такая же ситуация и с портом 443, 5432 они тоже показываются закрытыми.

Comment: Стоит обратиться к провайдеру, вероятно он блокирует доступ к этим портам (для защиты от вирусов, спама и прочего). P.S. а ты уверен, что тебе нужен доступ к СУБД `PostgreSQL` из интернета (порт `5432`)? Обычно это плохая идея.

Comment: Да в период разработки нужен, так как я обычно кодю не дома :)